# How do you remove Attachements in an email to email flow?

Tags: mule, email-attachments

I was trying to remove an attachment so that my outbound email only contains the payload. I  used the attachment transformer but the attchments are still being sent even if I used "*" as the filter. I have placed it on the inbound and the outbound endpoint but the attchment is still appering on the email

```
 <remove-attachment attachmentName="&quot;*&quot;" doc:name="Attachment"/>


<flow name="ocr_app_testFlow">
    <pop3:inbound-endpoint host="mail.awh.com.au" user="knaufack" password="ocr123" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="POP3"/>
    <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.subject]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <remove-attachment attachmentName="*" doc:name="Attachment"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[wildcard('*Succeeded*',message.inboundProperties.subject)]">
            <set-variable variableName="Subject" value="#[message.inboundProperties.subject]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="Warehouse" value="#[message.inboundProperties.subject.substring(40,43)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="Order" value="#[message.inboundProperties.subject.substring(44,51)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-variable variableName="Subject" value="#[message.inboundProperties.subject]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="Warehouse" value="#[message.inboundProperties.subject.substring(37,40)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <set-variable variableName="Order" value="#[message.inboundProperties.subject.substring(41,48)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <logger message="#[flowVars.Order] from #[flowVars.Warehouse]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-payload value="Your Order #[flowVars.Order] from #[flowVars.Warehouse] Warehouse is imported succesfully. Please Verify" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <remove-attachment attachmentName="*" doc:name="Attachment"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[flowVars.Warehouse  == 'ROC']">
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail.awh.com.au" user="tupload" password="upload123" to="tupload@awh.com.au" from="AWH_Logistics_Integration" subject="AWH OCR Process Notification" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="ROC Warehouse"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail.awh.com.au" user="tupload" password="upload123" to="pauldominguez@awh.com.au" from="AWH_Logistics_Integration" subject="AWH OCR Process Notification" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: Have you tried `attachmentName="*"` ? I'm not sure about this double-quoting business.

Comment: Hi David, yes I have tried this as well. This was generated by mule when I placed the "*" on the name field of the attachment transformer

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on `org.mule.transformer.simple.RemoveAttachmentTransformer.transformMessage` and follow what's going on in there? Is `message.removeOutboundAttachment` called at all?

Comment: Hi David, Im not sure how to go about it but I have placed a breakpoint using the debugger but the attachment is still there and not being deleted even if it came across the Attachment transformer. Any thoughts?

Comment: What was the value of `matchedValue` when this line was called https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/91f36d45a0b0744cd36f2c3037618aa7f5a655b1/core/src/main/java/org/mule/transformer/simple/RemoveAttachmentTransformer.java#L52 ? Did it iterate for all the attachments?

Comment: Hmm I tried to put a logger to trap the outbound attachment values and the value is null but still receives the email with attachment

Comment: [[OCR_Test_Flow].ocr_app_testFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [0, Knauff_ROC_3510254_0403201610290345.xml]
[[OCR_Test_Flow].ocr_app_testFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [0, Knauff_ROC_3510254_0403201610290345.xml]
INFO  2016-03-08 15:22:53,345 [[OCR_Test_Flow].ocr_app_testFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.transformer.simple.RemoveAttachmentTransformer: Attachment key expression return null, no attachment will be removed

Comment: Apprently, the inboundAttachement properties has the value but still passes it through the flow. the outboundattchment has null values

Comment: Mmmmh, at this point I'd say it's a bug that needs reporting to MuleSoft.

Comment: Thanks for the advise david . will log a customer support ticket for this. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the attached transformer class to your project.

```html
package org.awh.pfinder;

import org.mule.transport.email.transformers.ObjectToMimeMessage;

public class RemoveAttachmentTransformer extends ObjectToMimeMessage {
    
    public RemoveAttachmentTransformer() {
        super();
        setUseInboundAttachments(false);
    }

}
```

2. Add an SMTP connector and set that transformer as the outbound one: